# Hydrolysis of an ester

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, alcohols, esters, hydrolysis

> An organic compound **X** of formula $\ce{C5H10O2}$ forms two compounds when boiled in aqueous sodium hydroxide solution. One of these compounds forms a ketone when treated with acidified potassium dichromate.
>
> Compound **X** could be
>
> \begin{array}{ll}
> \textbf{A} \quad \ce{CH3COOCH(CH3)2}. \qquad & \textbf{C} \quad \ce{CH3CH2COOCH2CH3}. \\
> \textbf{B} \quad \ce{CH3CH2CH2CH2COOH}. \qquad & \textbf{D} \quad \ce{(CH3)2CH2COOCH3}.
> \end{array}

Can someone confirm that the correct answer is option **A** instead of **C**?

Since one of the compounds (alcohol) forms a ketone, therefore it must be secondary alcohol. This means the ester must be branched, so it would be **A**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oxidation of an alcohol (with potassium dichromate) gives a ketone when the alcohol is secondary, like isopropanol.  So, which ester out of the given choices has a secondary alcohol component?

You see that A is correct as claimed.